# Use range-datepicker package after adding it on package.json

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, package.json

I was wondering if somebody could help me with this issue, which hopefully will not be complicated.

I am running a project using Angular4, and I want to use this component.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/range-datepicker

I've tried to run `bower install range-datepicker`, but if then I use the `<range-datepicker>` tag in my project it won't recognise it.

In addition, I've added

```
"range-datepicker":"0.0.13"
```

to my package.json file, and running `npm install` it installs it and I can see the files in node_modules.

However, I still cannot use the `<range-datepicker>`, so I was wondering if someone can help me with this issue. I don't know if maybe I should add some script or style in my angular.json file

Comment: thats a real bad choice of lib, 50 downloads per week, use something with lots of downloads and decent docs, there's plenty of options out there

Comment: Are you getting parser error? Did you import the module into your app.module?

Comment: No, I didn't how should I do it? I mean, what's the module name of the lib?

Comment: I think it's not angular package

Answer (score 0):

That library does not provide an Angular component, but rather a WebComponent.

WebComponents are usable in Angular, but you need to take care of a few extra things.
I suggest that you look for documentation on using WebComponents in Angular.

Here's one link to get you started: https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2017/09/14/using-web-components-with-angular/